# Reading words from a file while ignoring spaces and ".,() In C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm writing a program that scan words from a text file

how can I  scan only the word that starts with space or number and end with a space

Without taking `',.()\t\n` to my string

I know i can use the function scanf but didn't quite get how to use it that way

Another small question

I'm looking to count how many lines there are in my text 
so I guess I should look for a "\n" sign to increase my count right?

Comment: If you read with `fgets` as xing advises, you can easily count the lines.

Comment: If a file does not end with a `'\n'`, example it only had `"abc"`.  Would that be a 0 line file or a 1 line file for your application?

Comment: "I'm writing a program that scan words" --> Post that talk about code rather than posts code attracts down-votes.  Suggest posting your code.

Comment: @xing, `strsep()` is better than `strtok()` to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you ask a question you need to follow some rules, here is a like for how to ask questions in stack overflow:

[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow Help Center

If I was doing this task I would read it char by char using a 'while loop' ends at EOF and inside of it a 'if' checks if you should add this char to your string and adding it using realloc.

For your second question put another 'if' before the first one that checks if the char == to '\n' and if so ++ to a int that count number of lines.

At the end it should look like this:

```
int *input = malloc(sizeof(int));
int linesLength = 0;
int now;
int lines = 0;
whlie ((now = getc(file)) != EOF){
    if (now == '\n') {
        lines += 1;
    }
    if (/* what chars you want out */){
        /* add your char using realloc */
        linesLength += 1;
    }
}
```

Btw this is the exact same task I need to do till the 18 to this month and your name looks familiar, the point is, this is not a site for homework, pay attention for this next time.

Comment: `fgets()` and drop brain damaged idea of `realloc()` on character basis.

Comment: Why brain damaged @0andriy?!?! First this is rude, second post a answer if you think he should use fgets().

Comment: I am a little confused by your code. I don't see it doing anything with `input`, but this line is certainly wrong: `int *input = malloc(sizeof(int*));`. This should be: `int *input = malloc(sizeof(int));`, or better: `int *input = malloc(sizeof *input);`. If you meant to use `char` here, with the second version you need only change the type on the left. Also, it is wildly inefficient to `realloc()` for every character added to a storage buffer. Better to reallocate to a reasonable size periodically as necessary, trimming to final size at the end if desired.

Comment: Ok ill fix that. I'm using int because with char there might be a problem with reading EOF. Also I'm aware that thats inefficient its just the beginning of the code so he will be able to improve it later. @DavidBowling

Comment: Fair enough about the inefficiencies; but I see no need to use `int` for the `input` buffer. Yes, using `int` for `now` is correct since code needs to be able to handle `EOF`, but the value of `EOF` won't be _stored_ in the `input` buffer, I think.

Comment: Oh, well I guess you are right, but may be other char he wants to get will be needed to be saved and only in int, any way better save than sorry.